# Getting python xarray to work on windows

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to open a list of hdf4 files (specifically HDF-EOS MOD11 files) using xarray in python on windows:

```
import xarray, glob

files = glob.glob(r'E:\data\*.hdf')
dates = [ some_func(f) for f in files] # gives a list of datetime objects
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(files, engine='netcdf4', concat_dim=dates)
```

however I get the following error:

> OSError: NetCDF: Unknown file format

I get the same error if I try to open any of the files using netcdf4

I am using python 3.52, xarray 0.92 and netcdf4 1.2.7, all installed using 64 bit anaconda on windows 7

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get netCDF4 and xarray working by reinstalling python using the latest version of anaconda (4.3.1, windows 64 bit installer), and installing the packages with conda (python=3.6.0, netcdf4=1.2.7, xarray=0.9.2).

Answer (score 0):

I believe whether HDF4 works with netCDF4 depends on how the netCDF libraries were installed, which would depend on how Anaconda built netCDF for Python. You might try asking on the Python-NetCDF4 [bug tracker](https://github.com/unidata/netcdf4-python) or trying the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io/) conda channel.